# Converter with objects, arrays passed variable through functions

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops, object

In a coding exercise I need to build a crypto currency converter.

It should - for the sake of exercise - start with a function that passes data to other functions. Only the first function should be called cascading to the respective result.

1. **addCurrency** (will take **3 arguments** and check if currency in a database called crypt)
2. **findcurrency** (will take the essential values from the first function and pass them to the next)
3. **converter** (will do the acutal conversion
4. **tellConversion** ("You will receive {AMOUNT} usd for your 2 {COINS_NAME}")

addCurrency takes 3 arguments: a coin, its value (amount of coins) and an array of coins (the coins database) so that a sample call could look like this

> addCurrency({coin:'bitcoin', rate:8000}, 2, crypt)

**If the coin is NOT in the database, it should return:**

> "New coin {YOUR_NEW_ADDED_COIN_GOES_HERE} added to Database"

but with the coins name capitalized!!! & store the coin in crypt.

**If the coin is in the database it should return**

> "You will receive {AMOUNT} usd for your 2 {COINS_NAME}"

**THIS IS MY CODE.** There are two issues: not sure how to capitalize and the converter doesn't work ( not sure why).

> Anyone who can help me?

```
var crypt = []; // define our database

var addCurrency = function (coin, value, crypt) {
    debugger;
    var indexObject = null; //helper variable to check coin in database

    //does the coin exist 
    for (var i = 0; i < crypt.length; i++) { //loop through the crypt in order to ...
        var obj = crypt[i].coin; //... set a variable with the current iterations coin name 
        if (obj == coin.coin) {//if that object happens to be the passed in coins'name ...
            indexObject = obj; //... set the value of indexObject to that value (want to store it for futre cod)
        }
    }

    //if coin not found, create a new one
    if(indexObject == null) { //... if the helper stays null ...
        //coin.coin = coin.coin.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + coin.coin.slice(1) //capitalize crypto currency

        indexObject = { //set index object with ...
            "coin": coin.coin, "rate": coin.rate //...this object patter
        }
        crypt.push(indexObject);
        return `New coin ${coin.coin} added to Database`
    //here passing between variable start. conversion rate is passed to findcurrency function
    } else {
        var passedOn = coin.rate
        var value = value
        findcurrency(passedOn, value)
    }
}

function findcurrency(passedOn, value) {
    converter(passedOn, value)
}

function converter(passedOn, value) {
    var converted = passedOn * value
    tellConversion(converted, value)
}

function tellConversion(converted, value) {
     return `You will receive ${converted} usd for your 2 ${value}`
}
```

Comment: Please if you try to help me, do not alter the code above substantially, but rather try to keep as much of my (beginners') logic in tact. I'm sure there are way better ways to solve this

Comment: For your first issue there's the String.toUpperCase() method. For your 2nd issue, example input would go a long way ;)

Comment: @AndreNuechter thx. well I thought I gave an example: addCurrency({coin:'bitcoin', rate:8000}, 2, crypt)

Comment: I saw that, but what's the content of 'crypt'? Am I supposed to make up examples?

Comment: @AndreNuechter crypt is an empty array data base at the beginning

Comment: `array.push(indexObject);` I don't think you mean to do this.

Comment: Not sure ... I mean "push the object into the database array" (crypt)

Comment: @OP, since 'crypt' is defined within the function, it will always be an empty array when you call the function. Perhaps you want to move it out.

Comment: ie `crypt.push(indexObject);`

Comment: @AndreNuechter thx for this. I put it outside the function now

Comment: CODE UPDATED: crypto array otuside function. What dosn't seem to work is passing on the data. checked in debugger. @AndreNuechter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not returning from the else-branch of addCurrency, findcurrency and converter.

Add 'return' before the last statements on those and it should work.

E.g.:

```
var crypt = []; // define our database

var addCurrency = function (coin, value, crypt) {
    debugger;
    var indexObject = null; //helper variable to check coin in database

    //does the coin exist 
    for (var i = 0; i < crypt.length; i++) { //loop through the crypt in order to ...
        var obj = crypt[i].coin; //... set a variable with the current iterations coin name 
        if (obj == coin.coin) {//if that object happens to be the passed in coins'name ...
            indexObject = obj; //... set the value of indexObject to that value (want to store it for futre cod)
        }
    }

    //if coin not found, create a new one
    if(indexObject == null) { //... if the helper stays null ...
        //coin.coin = coin.coin.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + coin.coin.slice(1) //capitalize crypto currency

        indexObject = { //set index object with ...
            "coin": coin.coin, "rate": coin.rate //...this object patter
        }
        crypt.push(indexObject);
        return `New coin ${coin.coin} added to Database`
    //here passing between variable start. conversion rate is passed to findcurrency function
    } else {
        var passedOn = coin.rate
        var value = value
        return findcurrency(passedOn, value)
    }
}

function findcurrency(passedOn, value) {
    return converter(passedOn, value)
}

function converter(passedOn, value) {
    var converted = passedOn * value
    return tellConversion(converted, value)
}

function tellConversion(converted, value) {
     return `You will receive ${converted} usd for your 2 ${value}`
}
```

Comment: Awesome Andre, do you think you can integrate the string to uppercase? I tried but I mix it up somewho.

Comment: Got it ... it has to be right in the return function :

  return `New coin ${coin.coin.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+coin.coin.slice(1)} added to Database`